# Excluding the first element from an iterator (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a generator function `A`.

For example (in reality I have a more complex function `A`),

```
def A():
    yield from [i**2 for i in range(20)]
```

Writing another generator function `B`, I want to enumerate all elements that `A` returns except the first element.

What are *concise* ways to implement this in Python 3?

Comment: Show the code you have for A

Comment: using `next()` ?

Comment: `_, *rest = your_iterator`

Comment: @dfundako: I tried to accomplish your request (see edited code), but: a. `A()` is somehow too complex, b. `A()` is not yet written :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, you don't need this in an expression, so you just call `next(it)`, ignoring the results, to consume and discard the first element.

---

However, if the iterator might be empty, you have to decide what you want to happen:

- Maybe you want to raise `StopIteration`, in which case `next(it)` is fine.
- Maybe you want to raise something else, in which case you `next(it)` inside an `except StopIteration: raise SomethingElse()`.
- Maybe you just want to leave the iterator empty, in which case you can call `next(it, None)`.

You can find examples of these in the stdlib and docs. For example, if you scan through the recipes in [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

This is doing exactly what you want to do—skip the first element of `b`. And if `iterable` is empty, you don't want an error here; you just want to iterate nothing. So, `next(b, None)`.

---

What if you need to do this in the middle of an expression?

Then you can write a function that skips the first element:

```
def skip_first(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    next(it, None)
    return it
```

(Again, you have to decide what you want to happen for an empty iterable.)

This returns a first-skipped version of the iterator, so you can use it inline. (It *also* mutates the iterator you passed in, of course, but you normally only use on a temporary value that you're not keeping any references to, so that's not a problem.)

Or, if you need to return a generator instead of an arbitrary iterator (usually you don't):

```
def skip_first(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    next(it, None)
    yield from it
```

Or you can use the more general version of the same idea, [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice). The following have the same effect:

```
it = skip_first(it)
it = itertools.islice(it, 1, None)
```

---

While we're on the `itertools` recipes, it's worth looking at `consume`:

```
def consume(iterator, n=None):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is None, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

Forget the `None` part; the interesting bit is that it skips `n` elements with an `islice` and a `next`. (Notice that it's mutating `iterator` in-place, not returning something.)

Answer (score 11):

Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
itertools.islice(generator,1,None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. was updating it myself.  The distinction here between this approach and others such as `first, *rest = generator` is that this will preserve the lazyness of the generator (rather than consuming the entire thing up front).

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: See @abarnert and @Solaxun's answers above.*

*Just thought that the following should be mentioned*

If you have e.g. `original = iter((1,2,3,4,5))`

Then

```
first, remaining = next(original), original
```

where `remaining` is the iterator without the first element.

---